# Duplicate a c# Windows Phone 8 App and Rename

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

Whats the best way of duplicating a c# Windows Phone 8 App and Rename everything in Visual Studio 2013, i tried copying all the files to a new solution and using fine & replace to replace the app name in the namespaces etc, but when you try to fun the app if fails and highlights 'throw' in the debugger.

Comment: You will get a much better response from a question which has a clear problem statement.  Right now,  you have suggested that you might be getting error messages, but you haven't mentioned what those errors are.  We can't really help you solve your issue if we don't know what the issue actually is....

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are talking about a Windows Phone 8 project. If so, fastest way is to copy-paste the folder that contains the solution. Then if you want to rename (the copied solution) it for any reason you can just rename, within Visual Studio, the solution and the project.

Comment: Do you have to change all the namespaces?

Comment: No, you don't need to, unless you want.